# Pechkin on DotNetNuke 7

Tags: iis-7, dotnetnuke, wkhtmltopdf, pechkin

i have tried to install wkhtmltopdf with Pechkin as dll in the DNN "bin" folder. But when i upload the pechkin.dll DNN crashes. I tried to upload the System.Drawing and System.Net dlls because i hope this was only a reference error. But nothing changed.

I hope someone here tried this too an can help me.

Kind Regards

Tiega

Answer (score 1):

What version of DNN are you running? What Framework is your Application Pool running under? Maybe you're still on 2.0 and maybe Pechkin requires 4.0? If so, change your application pool in IIS to 4.0.